# Mapping and serializing bidirectional associations

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I thought, this would be a trivial problem and would find the answer immediately, but somehow the Internet proved my assumptions wrong.

I have a model containing several entities that have all possible associations among themselves (1 to 1, 1 to many, many to many, aggregations, compositions, etc.). To make it simple, let's take this example. We have a Person class and a Car class. The person can own multiple cars, but a car can belong to only one person (so a 1 to many relationship). Now, it would be pretty simple to create a List/ArrayList in Person to keep the track of his/hers cars. However, I would like to keep track of the car's owner as well. So, the classes would look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Person Owner { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
    }
}
```

However, I believe, this structure would cause an infinite loop in Xml file, looking like this:

```
<Person name="John Doe">
  <Cars>
    <Car type="Ford">
      <Owner>
        <Person name="John Doe">
          <Cars>
            <Car type="Ford">
              <Owner>
                <Person name="John Doe">
      ... etc.
```

I have even tried it and during serialization I got the "You need to add XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute to the 'Owner' member." exception.

So, I have several questions: 
 1. Is there a way to prevent the loop in serialization?
 2. If not, do I have to code my own serializer for every class?
 3. Is this mapping OK? Or are there other/better approaches? I have thought about a central 'Mapper' class, that would return the desired object based on ID... but then again, this could be done via SQL. And I would like to avoid SQL (because of keeping the application light-weighted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` is a tree serializer, not a graph serializer. Your best bet is to avoid backwards navigation during serialization, for example by having:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Person Owner { get; set; }
```

("parent" and "owner" are almost always backwards navigation)

Unfortunately, `XmlSerializer` does not support post-serialization callbacks, otherwise it would be possible to add something like:

```
[WhateverOnAfterDeserialized]
public void OnAfterDeserialized(...) {
    foreach(var car in cars) car.Owner = this;
}
```

Some other serializers *do* support serialization callbacks, but by that token, those other serializers are likely to support full-graph serialization too. For example, `DataContractSerializer` can support both callbacks and full graphs, but it offers much less control over the xml.

Another option is to have a custom collection type that maintains the parent property as you add/remove; for example:

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly CarCollection cars;
    public Person() {
        cars = new CarCollection(this);
    }
    [XmlElement]
    public CarCollection Cars { get { return cars; } } 

    ...
}
```

with (in `CarCollection`):

```
// add code...
innerList.Add(value);
value.Parent = parent; // this is the field stored in the constructor
```

Personally, I think that's probably overkill.

Another option is to simply add a fix-up method that you call after deserialize, which does whatever is necessary (and cascades downwards):

```
public void FixupAfterDeserializer() {
    foreach(var car in cars) car.Parent = this;
}
```

Note that you would have to call this manually.

Finally, note that `[Serializable]` is not necessary for `XmlSerializer`.